# Circular import issue (class) - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, import

After a couple of hours of trying to debug a circular import issue I'd like to ask for some assistance here.

Please note, after researching, I'm unable to find my specific issue that would help.   Some issues I've found are based on `Button()`s inside the class. However, this is not the case.  My goal here is to `.get` an input from a text_box and convert it into json format aka beautify. (similar to what can be done in api testing tools)

I have a working function in `pointer.py` that does the job. However, I thought I'd create a class in a different file to clean things up a bit.

```
#--------------------------------------beautify_data.py--------------------------------------------#
import json
from pointer import text_box, payload_field

class Beautifier:
    def __init__(self, beautiful_payload):
        self.new = beautiful_payload

    def beautifying(self):
        json_object = json.loads(self.new) 
        new_json = json.dumps(json_object, indent=4) 
        text_box.delete('1.0', "end")  # Deleting content in text box
        text_box.insert('1.0', new_json) # Inserting pretty printed data
        payload_field.set(new_json) # Setting another field with pp data
        return new_json

#--------------------------------------pointer.py--------------------------------------------#

from beautify_data import Beautifier

button_save_payload = ttk.Button(width=8, text="BEAUTIFY", command=lambda: [Beautifier(get_text_box)])
button_save_payload.place(x=1110, y=75)

text_box = Text(window, width=68, height=29, bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 17))
text_box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
text_box.place(x=420, y=70)
get_text_box = text_box.get("1.0", END)

mytest = Beautifier(get_text_box)
new = mytest.beautifying()
print(new)
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Beautifier' from partially initialized module 'beautify_data' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: It looks like in `beautify_data.py` you're importing variables from `pointer.py`, and in `pointer.py` you're importing the `Beautifier` class from `beautify_data.py`. You can kind of see this as a dog chasing its tail. I'd suggest just moving the content in `pointer.py` in `beautify_data.py` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to update the widgets in `pointer.py` instead, so you don't need to import `pointer.py` inside `beautify_data.py`:

###### beautify_data.py

```py
import json

class Beautifier:
    def beautifying(self, txt):
        try:
            json_object = json.loads(txt)
            new_json = json.dumps(json_object, indent=4) 
            return new_json
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as ex:
            print(ex)
```

###### pointer.py

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from beautify_data import Beautifier

def beautify_json():
    get_text_box = text_box.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    mytest = Beautifier()
    result = mytest.beautifying(get_text_box)
    if result:
        text_box.delete("1.0", END)
        text_box.insert(END, result)

window = Tk()

text_box = Text(window, width=68, height=29, fg="white", bg="black", insertbackground="white", font=("Helvetica", 17))
text_box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

button_save_payload = ttk.Button(width=8, text="BEAUTIFY", command=beautify_json)
button_save_payload.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of importing data from `pointer`, the code in `pointer` needs to give access to the widgets to your `Beautifier` class. You can do this in many ways - you could pass the data to `Beautifier.__init__`, or pass it to `beautifying`. Or, you could create a function in `pointer.py` that updates its own widgets, and pass that as a callback.

Here's an example of the latter, passing a callback to `Beautifier.__init__`:

#### beautify_data.py

```
class Beautifier:
    def __init__(self, beautiful_payload, callback=None):
        self.new = beautiful_payload
        self.callback = callback

    def beautifying(self):
        json_object = json.loads(self.new) 
        new_json = json.dumps(json_object, indent=4) 
        if self.callback:
            self.callback(new_json)
        return new_json
```

#### pointer.py

```
def update_ui(new_json):
    text_box.delete('1.0', "end")
    text_box.insert('1.0', new_json)
    payload_field.set(new_json)
...
mytest = Beautifier(get_text_box, update_ui)
new = mytest.beautifying()
...
```

---

I recommend removing `beautiful_payload` from `Beautifier.__init__` and instead pass it to `beautifying`. That way you can create one instance and then use it multiple times, instead of having to create a new instance each time you want use it.

#### beautify_data.py:

```
class Beautifier:
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        self.callback = callback

    def beautifying(self, payload):
        json_object = json.loads(payload) 
        new_json = json.dumps(json_object, indent=4) 
        if self.callback:
            self.callback(new_json)
        return new_json
```

#### pointer.py

```
...
mytest = Beautifier(callback=update_ui)
get_text_box = text_box.get("1.0", END)
new = mytest.beautifying(get_text_box)
...
```

Comment: Appreciate the insight/help Bryan .  I've tried a few things to initialize this from the Beautify Button is pressed on pointer.py (check the button_save_payload variable Button on my post).  Under this buttons command= param, I've tried a few things including 'new', 'update-ui', 'mytest'.  Any idea how I can put this process in motion from the Button click?